# Chrome Extension: Check if the user has rated

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, user-data

So I'm trying to add a little feature where once a specific action occurs, every so often i want to let them know that if they're enjoying the extension to leave a rating.

However I don't want to bug people that already have. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Show a star icon in your UI that'll open the reviews section on CWS.

Comment: @wOxxOm I've just added that, and I researched around it seems like there is no real way to do this.